# What is the equivalent command for 'maven build' in gradle

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find the difference between maven and gradle. I have created a simple java project and build it with maven and gradle. But my maven build builds faster than gradle build even though gradle official website states that gradle builds faster than maven.

tried in Jenkins
maven install (build successfully in 12 seconds)
gradle build (build successfully in 20 seconds)

Comment: Ah yes! [Duty calls](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Gradle wrapper for faster build

./gradlew build